# get controller name by page url

Tags: magento-1.9, url, controllers

I want to get the previous page controller action name from previous page URL in **Magento 1.9**.

I get the previous page url by this:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
```

Now I tried to get the controller name from page url.

My question is "How to get the controller action name from page url?"

Thanks.

Comment: You can try with Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();

Comment: by this code i get the current page controller name not the previous page controller name. @RakeshJesadiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
$refUrl = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
$refUrl = str_replace($baseUrl, '', $refUrl);
$previouController = explode("/", $refUrl);
echo $moduleName = (isset($previouController[0]) && $previouController[0]) ? $previouController[0] : '';
echo "<br>";
echo $controllerName = (isset($previouController[1]) && $previouController[1]) ? $previouController[1] : '';
echo "<br>";
echo $controllerAction = (isset($previouController[2]) && $previouController[2]) ? $previouController[2] : '';
echo "<br>"
```

Comment: ok i will try @abdul and let you know

Comment: @pooja wellcome :)

Comment: I am also trying to previous page controller's name but did not get it. By using above code, I just get url key. But did not get controller name. How can i get controller name

Comment: hi @VaibhavAhalpara can you please post your code here.

Comment: @VaibhavAhalpara can u share you code ?

Comment: i used same code that mention in above answer. And test with category page , product page and cms page

Comment: can u share print_r(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER')); result me? and are using which controller file?

Comment: http://example.com/home-decor/decorative-accents.html

Comment: url rewrite cases above code not working

Comment: Above code working only ref url format : example.com/customer/account/index/